# Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end when calling HTTP2 delete request

Tags: node.js, http2

I am trying to call HTTP2 delete request using Native Nodejs (http2) library but it is failing only for DELETE request. Please advise.

Here is the code:

```js
const http2 = require('http2');

const arrayData = ['deb96c57-52ff-4ccb-9088-d421b1856724'];

const arrayString = JSON.stringify(arrayData);

const client = http2.connect('url'); // Replace with your API hostname

const request = client.request({
  ':method': 'DELETE',
  ':path': '/path', // Replace with your API endpoint
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'content-length': Buffer.byteLength(arrayString),
});

request.on('response', (headers, flags) => {
  let responseData = '';

  request.on('data', (chunk) => {
    responseData += chunk;
  });

  request.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Response:', responseData);
  });
});

request.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
request.write(arrayString);

request.end();

client.on('close', () => {
  console.log('Client session closed.');
});
```

Below error appears when the script is run. Does delete request support body in HTTP2?

```
Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
      at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
      at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:321:11)
      at ClientHttp2Stream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:336:10)
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised `DELETE` bodies aren't supported. It would be good design to try and avoid features that are not recommended by the http specs. `DELETE` and `GET` should not have a body.

Comment: The API has been implemented for a long time and it has been configured to HTTP2 recently. Is there a possible solution to accomplish this in Native NodeJs?

Comment: Well, you could consider just going back to HTTP/1.1 for these kinds of broken requests as a fallback. Maybe you can build some logic like: "If the method is DELETE, and there's a request body switch back to HTTP/1.1"

Comment: The API has been for Ages and recently our companay decided to roll it on HTTP2 and we cannot do that for one request.

Comment: It would be very unusual for an endpoint to only support HTTP/2. All of them also usually do HTTP/1.1. Your only only recourse beyond that is to roll your own HTTP/2 client. I would suggest you fix the root cause instead. I think 'can not do this' is an excuse and you're looking for an easy workaround, whcih is understandable but it may not exist in this case.